# Visual studio intellisense window for numeric literal?

Tags: visual-studio

when we press . (dot) key after any character and string literal visual studio open intellisense window but not for numeric literal. I want to why visual studio don't do that for numeric? what the technical reason is behind this.

Comment: What do you want intellisense to do in case you press . for a numeric literal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `8.9` is a number, and to get there you type `8` + `.`, thus `8.` could become a number.

Intellisense on decimal numbers could get annoying really quickly.